# Omega 4: Export settings to .info

Tags: theming

I'm sure its a simple question but i cannot find any resource to the solution.

In Omega 4, i keep getting this message "The settings for this theme are currently served from a variable. You might want to export them to your .info file".

So how do i do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

drush omega-export
drush omega-revert

or

omega-export --revert

See: http://friendlymachine.net/posts/getting-started-omega-4

Answer (score 1):

I don't have drush on my machine (issues with installation), so i copied theme-settings from Omega and placed it in to the sub-theme and then opened it in Notepad++ and copied and replaced with my new theme name. That message has now gone.

Answer (score -2):

you have to run  'drush omega-guard' and the error will desapear

Comment: omega-guard is for watching SCSS files